# Mathematical Function in Python does not work properly?

Tags: python, macos, math, integral

```
def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = float(b - a) / n
    s = 0.0
    s = s + f(a)
    i=1
         while i<=n-1:
         s = s + f(a + i*h)
    i= i +1
    s = s + f(b)
    s = s*h
return s
def f(x):
    x = float(x)
    return (-1/6)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x+2)*(x-4)
lel = trapezoidal(f, -2, 4, 10)
print ("%.3f" % lel)
ok = f(-0.8)
print ok
```

I am trying to build a program that calculates integrals using the trapezoid rule. When I do it on paper it works fine but my f function does not work properly. For example f(-0.8) should be equal to 4.8384 but when I run it shows 29.0304. Please help?

Comment: `print` is your friend. be more friendly

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: If this is Python 2, `-1/6` isn't the value you think it is.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python 2.x

```
def f(x):
    x = float(x)
    return (-1/6)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x+2)*(x-4)
```

The first term in your expression is doing integer division. The result of that division will be promoted to `float` later during the multiplication, but it is too late by then.

```
>>> (-1/6)
-1
```

You need to keep everything in `floats`

```
def f(x):
    x = float(x)
    return (-1.0/6.0)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x+2)*(x-4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return (-1.0/6)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x+2)*(x-4)
```